# Embedded C code unexplainable syntax error; Expected ... before '{' token

Tags: c, compiler-errors, embedded, syntax-error, interrupt-handling

I started to use Eclipse right now and I noticed that there is this one error occuring, at every function that I write. Nothing helps with that yet.

```
#include "init.h"
#include "irq.h"

void T0Handler (void) _attribute_ ((interrupt ("IRQ")));


int main(void)
{
    systemInit(); /*CCLK = 50MHz; PCLK = 25MHz*/

    install_irq(TIMER0_INT, T0Handler, 0);

    for(;;);
}
```

Above is just an initializing code snippet.

However, an error pops up saying:

Description    Resource    Path    Location    Type
expected '=', ',', ';', 'asm' or '**attribute**' before '{' token   assignment1.c   Template_Proteus    line 14 C/C++ Problem

it cannot be true in terms of main func. as it expects those tokens written in-between main() and the main's opening curly bracket.

Such problems are occuring at every function I write in Eclipse (working in Virtualbox).

Also, in the T0Handler declaration, there is constant syntax issue with the

`_attribute_ ((interrupt ("IRQ")))` part.

Comment: Is that error message generated from the exact code you posted?

Comment: If you just started using Eclipse, there's still time to turn around. It's "free" for a reason. Free as in, if you don't value your time at all and you are happy to trouble-shoot strange IDE errors instead of doing actual programming.

Comment: @Lundin Hi we have to use it in our school. And now that I am home because of the pandemic I'm having tough times with that IDE.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Eclipses' parser (which is what is driving the in-editor highlights) does not understand the compiler-specific extension that you are using.

Not sure how to work around this, but it's a common enough problem in embedded development I think.

I found an answer [adapted from here](https://www.eclipse.org/forums/index.php/t/1094826/) that states that you can fix it by writing code targeting Eclipse's indexer like so:

```
#ifdef __CDT_PARSER__
#define _attribute_ (...)
#endif
```

I have not tested this.